# how to release a tabbarcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

A `UITabBarController's` `viewControllers` are `navigationController`, when I release the `tabbarcontroller`, I found the memory would not released ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant release them if you create them in .xib file. **They will be released then your application end work !!!**

Comment: really? if I alloc a tabbarcontroller,then release it,alloc again,release again...   the memory wouldnot release before i exit the app?

Answer (score 0):

### you should release them in dealloc method of app delegate class

```
- (void)dealloc {

   [tabbarcontroller release]; 
   [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: could you describe the detail, the tabbarcontroller was not in app delegate class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in code you probably need to release the navigationControllers after adding them to the tabBarController...

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *controllerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

UINavigationController *localNavigationController;

AccountViewController *accountViewController = [[AccountViewController alloc] init];
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:accountViewController];
[controllerArray addObject:localNavigationController];
[localNavigationController release];
[accountViewController release];

AccountHistoryViewController *accountHistoryViewController = [[AccountHistoryViewController alloc] init];
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:accountHistoryViewController];
[controllerArray addObject:localNavigationController];
[localNavigationController release];
[accountHistoryViewController release];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:controllerArray];
[controllerArray release];
```